# Load Image time inconsistant (jQuery/PHP/HTML)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery to create a simple slide show.

I have a slideshow in home.php file. I have a menubar. when I click home in the menu, I load home.php in the content div of main page. There is no problem neither with slideshow nor with menu. When combined, they work fine upon first load. However when loaded many times, the time interval is not perfect and works with unequal irratic load pattern.
Here is my code in home.php

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});
</script>
```

and in menu.php

```
<li><a href=# onclick="$('#content').load('home.php') ;return false">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href=# onclick="$('#content').load('buyitems.php') ;return false">BUY</a></li>
<li><a href=# onclick="$('#content').load('discuss.php') ;return false">DISCUSS</a></li>
<li><a href=# onclick="$('#content').load('locationnear.php') ;return false">NEAR YOU</a></li>
```

If you need details, let me know.

**Problem**
They work perfect individually. When I click home on menubar several times, the fade in time is not constant. some images load faster, others slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your delayed animation execution is probably the jQuery animation queue.

New animations like your `fadeOut` are queued and wait for previous animations on the same element to finish.

To cancel the current queue you might use `jQuery.stop()` <kbd>[stop - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)</kbd>

> Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

So in your case this might look like this:

```
$('.fadein :first-child').stop(true, true).fadeOut()
```

Or you disable queuing for this animation <kbd>[fadeOut - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)</kbd>

> A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately.

```
$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut({ queue : false })
```

---

*Edit*

For every time you click your code starts a new `setInterval` which will also add animations to the queue so maybe clearing the intervall will help:

```
if (window.currenTimer) {
  clearInterval(window.currentTimer);
}
window.currentTimer = setInterval(function(){
  $('.fadein :first-child')
   .stop(true, true)
   .fadeOut()
   .next('img')
   .stop(true, true)
   .fadeIn()
   .end()
   .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It actually becomes faster not slower. After your suggestion I modified: "<li><a href=# onclick="$('.fadein :first-child').stop(true, true).fadeOut();$('#content').load('home.php') ;return false">HOME</a></li>" which did not work. Where should add the code. I initially added it before "$(function(){
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();" which did not work so had to try adding in link instead. None are working, though. Any suggestions.

Comment: Could you please try to explain step by step what should happen?

Comment: Nothing fancy! I will slightly modify naming for clarity. I have three .php files. a menu.php, an index.php, a slideshow.php The menu contains slideshow as an option. The slideshow.php contains slideshow. The index contains seperate div s one for menu and another for container div. When slideshow is clicked in index page, I want to load slideshow.php in container div. Everything is fine up to this point. When I load page, it works. When I click slideshow in menu, the slideshow is loaded in div with animation playing. Problem is: When I click slideshow in menu several times, the animation...

Comment: ... rate increases-movie plays faster and faster the more I click on slideshow in menu. Hope that's more clear. What should happen is obviously: movie should play at constant rate whether I click on slideshow in menu once or 10 or hundred times.

Comment: danke! Where should that go again? before "$(function(){
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();" in the script right?